# Error while serializing queryset object in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am trying to serialize my `queryset` object and getting error as below,

```
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `fullName` on serializer `UserSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `QuerySet` instance.
Original exception text was: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'fullName'.
```

**Traceback**

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/crud/

Django Version: 1.9
Python Version: 2.7.10
Installed Applications:
['rest_framework',
 'background_task',
 'userApp',
 'imageUpload',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\JpG\Desktop\herokuEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\JpG\Desktop\herokuEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\JpG\Desktop\herokuEnv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  58.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\JpG\Desktop\herokuEnv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\viewsets.py" in view
  87.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\JpG\Desktop\herokuEnv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in dispatch
  466.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)

File "C:\Users\JpG\Desktop\herokuEnv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in dispatch
  463.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\JpG\Desktop\CYC_Heroku\userApp\views.py" in create
  24.             return Response(data=serializer.data)  # {"detail": "Mobile Number already exist"})

File "C:\Users\JpG\Desktop\herokuEnv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in data
  503.         ret = super(Serializer, self).data

File "C:\Users\JpG\Desktop\herokuEnv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in data
  239.                 self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)

File "C:\Users\JpG\Desktop\herokuEnv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in to_representation
  463.                 attribute = field.get_attribute(instance)

File "C:\Users\JpG\Desktop\herokuEnv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\fields.py" in get_attribute
  422.             raise type(exc)(msg)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /user/crud/
Exception Value: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `fullName` on serializer `UserSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `QuerySet` instance.
Original exception text was: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'fullName'.
```

I'm including some code snippet here .
**views.py**

```
class UserView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = UserModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            mobNum = request.data.get('mobileNum')        
            if UserModel.objects.filter(mobileNum=mobNum).exists():            
                serializer=UserSerializer(UserModel.objects.filter(mobileNum=mobNum))
                return Response(data=serializer.data)
```

**serializer.py**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

**models.py**

```
class UserModel(models.Model):
    fullName = models.CharField(max_length=100)    
    mobileNum = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    isAuthority = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

**My sample Input** [image: Screenshot]

Actually, I am expecting an output similar to the output of below code

```
class UserView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = UserModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return Response(data=serializer.data)
```

Comment: can you put your UserModel and your posted data

Comment: @SnakeFcz Updated question with models.py and input screenshot

Answer (score 0):

try `get()` instead of `filter()` 
That is, `serializer=UserSerializer(UserModel.objects.get(mobileNum=mobNum))`

Full `views.py`

```
class UserView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = UserModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            mobNum = request.data.get('mobileNum')        
            if UserModel.objects.filter(mobileNum=mobNum).exists():            
                serializer=UserSerializer(UserModel.objects.get(mobileNum=mobNum))
                return Response(data=serializer.data)
```